# Transforming an array of strings column to an array of integer column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table, called `resource_schedules` which contains a :

```
t.string :active_patient_ids, array: true, default: []
```

I want to transform it to :

```
t.integer :active_patient_ids, array: true, default: []
```

I've created a migration file and here is the code I've put inside it:

```
def up
    change_column :resource_schedules, :active_patient_ids, :integer
end

def down
    change_column :resource_schedules, :active_patient_ids, :string
end
```

Then I ran this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The point is my `active_patient_ids` is still an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

At no point in the migrations above are you actually changing the data-type of what is in the table. If there's data already in the table you're going to have a hard time converting between data types via a migration. I recommend making a new, empty int table and then manually migrating the data from the string table to the int table using `string.to_i`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate the data as well.  Since you want to use the same column name, you should be able to rename the existing column, add a new column using the previous name, then migrate the data.

I haven't tested this, but I've done used something similar before.  PLEASE backup your db before trying it.

```
def up
  rename_column :resource_schedules, :active_patient_ids, :active_patient_id_strings
  add_column :resource_schedules, :active_patient_ids, :integer

  ResourceSchedule.each do |schedule|
    schedule.active_patient_ids = schedule.active_patient_id_strings.map { |s| s.to_i }
    schedule.save
  end

  remove_column :resource_schedules, :active_patient_id_strings
end
```